# How can I install Ubuntu Landscape on my LAN?

Tags: 12.04, landscape

I am planning to install ubuntu landscape server for my local network, can any one share me installation document of it and also please tell me what are the basic setup requirement (software & hardware)

I have a trial account on https://landscape.canonical.com/, and I want to register my system on it, how I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

To register a new client on the hosted landscape server follow the instructions linked in the grey box to the left of the screen when you have logged in to Landscape (right under where it tells you how many computers are registered in your account).  The link text reads "following these instructions.".

Installing Landscape on your own network is a more involved task.  For most use cases the hosted product is a good answer, but if you're in a situation where a local instance is  appropriate the first step would be to start talking to Canonical.  You can make contact here: http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/contact

To learn more about Landscape Dedicated Server's architecture, see:

- [Release notes for latest Landscape Dedicated Server](https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/ReleaseNotes12.09)
- [Recommended deployment](https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/RecommendedDeployment12.09)
- [Server install quickstart](https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/QuickStart)

Comment: how can I install a LDS on a local server (ubuntu 14.04lts) via ppa?n thanks

Comment: See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/549809/how-do-i-install-landscape-for-personal-use

Comment: i've already tried to add that ppa but i received this error "Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:landscape/14.10'. Please check that the PPA name or format is correct. " I think it's not adapt for 14.04.   I known that: for <= 12.04 sudo apt-get install python-software-properties. While for >= 12.10 sudo apt-get install software-properties-common.. I've already done it but nothing I've check that seeing also this guide http://pricklytech.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/ubuntu-server-14-4-trusty-add-apt-repository-command-not-found/