# How do I install Landscape for personal use?

Tags: landscape

I'd like to manage my home machines and laptops with Landscape, how can I do this?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

## For Ubuntu 16.04 or 14.04 LTS

You can install Landscape directly on a machine running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, this is called "Landscape On Premises." It is free for up to 10 physical (or virtual) machines and 50 containers:

#### Deploying a single server

**WARNING:** landscape-quickstart modifies apache configuration files, **DO NOT DO THIS ON AN EXISTING SERVER INSTALLATION** without understanding what you are getting into.

Just install the Landscape Quickstart package:
Check [here](https://landscape.canonical.com/set-up-on-prem) for changes to the below instructions:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:landscape/17.03
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install landscape-server-quickstart
```

After it finishes, access it with a browser like `https://hostname.example.com/`

Where `hostname.example.com` is the output of `hostname -f` on that machine, or just `hostname` if that fails to resolve.

### Using Landscape

You should then see the web UI after filling in your name and contact details:

[image: Account dashboard with 20 remaining registrations]

Click on the link highlighted to add client machines:

[image: Registration instructions]

Follow those instructions on the *client* you want to join to Landscape. Note the following line:

```
sudo landscape-config --computer-title "My Web Server" --account-name standalone  --url https://<servername>/message-system --ping-url http://<servername>/ping
```

You can customize the title and so forth for each machine. See the [landscape-config man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/landscape-config.1.html) for more information.

After you type in the `landscape-config` command the client will ask you some questions, those are optional, you can just hit Enter until the client restarts, then you can accept the client in the web UI.

### Registering clients with a self signed certificate:

The quickstart package installs a self-signed certificate that is generated on-the-fly.

- Grab this file from the server: `/etc/ssl/certs/landscape_server_ca.crt`
- Copy it somewhere on the client, for example, `/etc/landscape/landscape_server_ca.crt`
- Change `/etc/landscape/client.conf` to include this line, pointing at the file you just copied: `ssl_public_key = /etc/landscape/landscape_server_ca.crt`

Then try to register again. (Thanks to [panlinux](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/2mkc4u/til_landscape_has_a_free_selfhosted_trial_for_up/cm5yy23) for figuring this out)

### Further Reading:

- Landscape [website](https://landscape.canonical.com/)
- On-prem Landscape 17.03 [Release Notes](https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/ReleaseNotes17.03)

Comment: I get an error on command `sudo apt-get install landscape-server-quickstart` `E: Unable to locate package landscape-server-quickstart`

Comment: @prodigerati ...because you either didn't do the `add-apt-repository` or the `apt-get update`

Comment: deploying Landscape Server works well, but Landscape Client someone has ever tried to deploy that on a node? Because after I made that I can't register the node on my Landscape server. I've open also a post here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/918493/deploy-of-landscape-client-on-a-node

Comment: For the love of god, can we add a huge warning label at the start of this post "DO NOT DO THIS ON AN EXISTING APACHE INSTALLATION BEFORE YOU READ FURTHER"?

Comment: @pkExec, I added something.

Comment: Does Landscape work with Debian, or only Ubuntu?

Answer (score 16):

## For Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

On one machine install Ubuntu Server 16.04.01 LTS -> [Download Ubuntu Server 16.04.01 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server).
It is recommended to install `openssh-server` as well, this can be chosen during the process.
Once installed the Ubuntu Server operating system, install `landscape-server-quickstart`.
You also have to adjust the firewall to make everything working flawlessly without any issue.

Open a terminal - execute the following commands to accomplish these tasks :

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw allow http
sudo ufw allow https

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:landscape/16.06
sudo apt update
sudo apt install landscape-server-quickstart
```

After the installation is complete, you have to register the landscape account.
Because the Server has no GUI, you need to install a text based web browser :

```
sudo apt install links  
links https://<server-hostname>
```

Now register the Ubuntu Server - to do this you need the `landscape-client`.

```
sudo apt install landscape-client  
sudo landscape-config --account-name standalone --url https://<server-hostname>/message-system --ping-url http://<server-hostname>/ping
```

Backup the Landscape certificate, because it has to exist on every machine  you want to register :

```
sudo cp /etc/ssl/certs/landscape_server.pem /<external-media>/landscape_server.pem
```

To register additional Ubuntu systems, install the `landscape-client` package on each machine :

```
sudo apt install landscape-client
```

Copy over the Landscape certificate (which you saved before) and edit the `client.config` file :

```
sudo cp /<external-media>/landscape_server.pem /etc/landscape/landscape_server.pem  
sudo nano /etc/landscape/client.conf
```

Add this line : `ssl_public_key = /etc/landscape/landscape_server.pem` and save the change.

Now register the Ubuntu system the same way you did, when you registered the Ubuntu Server :

```
sudo landscape-config --account-name standalone --url https://<server-hostname>/message-system --ping-url http://<server-hostname>/ping
```

Open `https://<server-hostname>` in your web browser and accept all the pending computers.

Additional information : The free license covers 10 bare metal machines and 50 LXC containers !

#### References

- [landscape.canonical.com](https://landscape.canonical.com/)
- [help.landscape.canonical.com](https://help.landscape.canonical.com/)

Comment: IMO we should recommend using another browser/PC to hit the landscape URL instead of installing links on the server.

Comment: @JorgeCastro : When you install LOP on a machine which runs the desktop edition of Ubuntu, of course any other browser can be used ... when you install LOP on a server without a GUI, you need a text based web browser, such as links, that is mainly the reason why I suggested to use links in the instructions and once the account is registered, one can access landscape from any attached computer with any browser though ... links is only needed for the registration process of the standalone account from the server. :)

Comment: Note that you may need to install `python-software-properties` or `software-properties-common` to get the `add-apt-repository` command.

Comment: Already read that, but use quickstart and not juju deploy

Comment: @cl-netbox the result is that: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23910833/

Comment: @cl-netbox all software have been upgraded using their ppa stable

Comment: @RiccardoMagrini Well, then you should contact the juju -> https://launchpad.net/~juju/+archive/ubuntu/stable and the landscape -> https://launchpad.net/~landscape/+archive/ubuntu/16.06 teams and report the bug/error.

Answer (score 3):

Along with the other answers, https://landscape.canonical.com is always available.  This is a hosted service that you can sign up for a 30 day demo to see if it meets your needs, and does not require you to go through the steps needed to set up your own server.

Answer (score 3):

For those on ARM processor installations of Ubuntu 14.04, it seems that while the [15.11 PPA has an ARMHF package](http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/15.11/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/), using `landscape-server-quickstart` is not available (ie an `apt-get update` doesn't find that command).  Thus, using @andreas **Deploying for Scale Out** method is the only one which works ([per landscape docs](https://help.landscape.canonical.com/FrontPage)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install juju-core juju-deployer juju-quickstart

juju-quickstart u/landscape/landscape-dense-maas
```

Using `landscape-dense-mass` avoids setting up MAAS or planning for autoscaling.  This was a good fit approach where I wanted to simply use Landscape to monitor an existing fixed number of Ubuntu 14.04 servers.