# Where to install Juju

Tags: server, juju, 14.10, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I'm reading the question at
[How do I install Landscape for personal use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549809/how-do-i-install-landscape-for-personal-use?newsletter=1&nlcode=102391|e261)
and have a question regarding the install of Juju:
Is Juju to be installed on the "Landscape Dedicated Server"?

Answer (score 4):

Juju is a dependency of Landscape. When you install Landscape (via apt-get, for example), the right version of Juju will also be installed. It will only be used, though, if you start the OpenStack Autopilot.

If you want to install Landscape via Juju, however, you can, and there are advantages. You will get an installation that can scale as your number of registered machines grows. In other words, you get it right from the start. Quickstart was always meant to be just a quick demonstration.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan on using the autopilot openstack installer, then yes, you need to install juju on the same machine as where Landscape is installed.  The package dependencies take care of this for you so you shouldn't need to do anything extra.

The autopilot installer uses juju to deploy Openstack.