# how to install landscape server LDS (Dedicated Server) on ubuntu 14.04lts via ppa?

Tags: landscape

I'd like to install and test Landscape Dedicated Server (LDS) on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server but I don't know how to install it.
The only guides I found on the Internet are for Landascape client.

**As you've suggested me to see this guide**

[How do I install Landscape for personal use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549809/how-do-i-install-landscape-for-personal-use)

I've tried to add that ppa on Ubuntu 14.04Lts server but I received this error

```
"Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:landscape/14.10'. Please check that the PPA name or format is correct."
```

I think that ppa is not adapt for 14.04 and then I know that:

for <= 12.04 we have to use

**`$: sudo apt-get install python-software-properties`**

While for >= 12.10 the command is

**`$: sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`**

Comment: You should take a look at the excellent answer given in this [question][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/a/550625/1102

Comment: I've already read that. The solution is for an ubuntu 14.10 I'd like to install Landscape on ubuntu 14.04Lts.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood that answer. The solution *is* for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, it's using the 14.10 release of Landscape.

Comment: I didn't see any note about 14.04, then i've tried to add that ppa but ireceive this error "Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:landscape/14.10'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
" I think it's not adapt for 14.04

Comment: Can you check you have `python-software-properties` installed? Try running the `add-apt-repository` line with `-m` for debugging

Comment: I know that: for <= 12.04 sudo apt-get install python-software-properties. While for >= 12.10 sudo apt-get install software-properties-common.. I've already upgrade MaaS adding ppa using the second solution. I've check that seeing also this guide http://pricklytech.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/ubuntu-server-14-4-trusty-add-apt-repository-command-not-found/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18953/discussion-between-adam-collard-and-riccardo-magrini).

Comment: hi guys after our discuss in chat I've reported the error I received during the bootstrapping of node via Juju  
the command using to install Openstack is present on step 4  of this guide ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack. Juju made the bootstrapping of the node, the ubuntu installer started its procedure but at the end the node went in shut down and on MaaS reported this error paste.ubuntu.com/9235249 while on .commands.log that paste.ubuntu.com/9247586. All vnode use fastpath-installer.