# How do I install Landscape on an existing server?

Tags: landscape

I'm trying to install the personal use version of Landscape to manage my Ubuntu servers at home and I followed the instructions on this page: [How do I install Landscape for personal use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549809/how-do-i-install-landscape-for-personal-use)

However it completely took over my Apache config and stopped the other components I had running.

Can I run Landscape on a server with other components or do I have to give it a dedicated Ubuntu install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Landscape requires a dedicated install; Like most management systems, it is not made to "share" a web server with other workloads.

If you are using it just to manage a few machines for home use and load is therefore not an issue, you could run it within a virtual machine.  This is not a best practice for production, but it may work in your case - or you could simply use a cloud instance.

Answer (score 2):

The landscape-server-quickstart package is meant to be an easy way to try out Landscape, but as a consequence it "takes over" the machine as you say.

You can take more control over the Landscape installation if you want, but then you need to perform a few tasks manually, including future upgrades.

Take a look at this guide for the manual installation version:

[LDS/ManualInstallation14.10 | Landscape Help](https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/ManualInstallation14.10)

It has an Apache vhost template that you can tweak if you want, and as a result share your Apache installation with other services. But you are on your own there.

That guide is geared towards using two machines: one for the application, one for the database. You can install it all on the same machine if you want, of course, just adjust accordingly.