# Landscape is missing user information in web interface

Tags: 14.04, server, users, landscape

We have a custom installation of Ubuntu Landscape 15.01 in our network (using the instructions from here: [How do I install Landscape for personal use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549809/how-do-i-install-landscape-for-personal-use)), and installed several servers that connect to it.
All servers (14.04) were installed with the same packages and configurations and  connect to Landscape correctly.

However, some machines are missing the user information completely (in the Users tab of the web interface), as shown in the screenshots below.

What could be the reason for this behavior?

**Correct:**
[image]

**Incorrect:**
[image]

In the server logs, several times a "consecutive error" occurs. An example is shown below:

```
message-server.log.1-Jul  9 20:37:59 message-server-1 INFO  Processed messages for computer 24 (size=0.61kb, duration=0.21s, load=0.21, ignored=0, processed=1, dropped=1, remaining=1, client=14.12-0ubuntu0.14.04)
message-server.log.1:Jul  9 20:37:59 message-server-1 ERR  Error processing the payload for computer 24, consecutive errors: 1
#012Traceback (most recent call last):#012  File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/message/apis.py", line 361, in _process_messages#012    self.handle(message["type"], message)#012  File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/message/api.py", line 66, in handle#012    return handler(type, body)#012  File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/lib/arguments.py", line 79, in replacement#012    return original(*new_args, **new_kwargs)#012  File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/message/handlers/users.py", line 29, in __call__#012    self._create_group_members()#012  File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/message/handlers/users.py", line 203, in _create_group_members#012    "create-group-members")#012  File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/message/handlers/users.py", line 62, in _get_groups_by_names#012    u"users")#012ConsistencyError: Groups specified in the 'create-group-members' field don't exist: sudo
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check the client logs on those machines, under `/var/log/landscape`. Something prevented landscape from reading `/etc/passwd`.

Could also be that that computer is not exchanging correctly with the server. Are other pieces of information about it correct, like installed packages?

Grep for "consecutive error" in the message-server.log files on the server, under `/var/log/landscape-server`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Grepping for passwd in ```/var/log/landscape```  on the client shows no results. All other pieces of information (including packages) seem to be correct. In the server logs, "consecutive error" is mentioned several times. I'll update the question with them.