# Is there still a free version of Landscape and what are the limitations and alternatives?

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, landscape

I have a couple of VMs running loaded with Ubuntu and it would be a lot easier if i could manage them all from a Web GUI.

I did find this question [How do I install Landscape for personal use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549809/how-do-i-install-landscape-for-personal-use)

But when I try to add the PPA I am getting this:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:landscape/15.01'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

So if LDS isn't free anymore is there then an alternative where I can upgrade the packages and see the state of the servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LDS is still free and that PPA is still available.

I just confirmed by running the following on an up-to-date trusty machine:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:landscape/15.01
```

Comment: hmm that was odd mabey their repo was down when i tried

Comment: Could be. When there are network issues, the add-apt-repository tool doesn't print out a good error message.