# Landscape : Can't create an account : Personal server

Tags: 14.04, landscape

I have just installed Canocial Landscape and have followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549809/how-do-i-install-landscape-for-personal-use) guide.

After i am going to https://10.0.2.44 do i have to create account
So far so good,  but when i am clicking the `Sign Up` button do i get redirected to https://landscape/new-standalone-user and getting an "Server Not Found"

Answer (score 1):

You have a hostname/DNS issue. A quick fix would be to add an entry for "10.0.2.44 landscape" in the /etc/hosts file of the machine you are using to access landscape from.

Comment: i had some problems with my VM so i had to trash it, but i am gonna try this tomorrow