# Landscape - email notifications not working

Tags: postfix, landscape

I am running landscape as dedicated server and I am having problems to receive email notifications.

the system emails address is set to landscape@mydomain.com
receiving mail alerts@mydomain.com
also tried to set the receiving to a gmail one but also not receiving.

is there somewhere an option to set the smtp manually?

I did the installation steps provided in this tutorial without juju ([How do I install Landscape for personal use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549809/how-do-i-install-landscape-for-personal-use)). did I miss something?

Comment: you can set postfix to use an SMTP server instead and relay things.  it's how my landscape instance is set up

Comment: ah ok! postfix configuration looks for me a little bit complex - do you know if it will work with ssmtp also?

Comment: not sure if you need to remove postfix to install that, but the Landscape LDS software has a package dependency on `postfix` so removing `postfix` will remove Landscape.

Answer (score 1):

You can instruct Postfix to use a different `smtp` server (i.e to act as a 'relay'), rather than send mail natively as itself instead to mail addresses.

[This post on Linode's documentation on things](https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/postfix-smtp-debian7) should be able to help you configure postfix to send smtp through a remote SMTP server (such as Google Mail, etc.).

This is how my landscape server is configured to send email notifications, although until I can replace my hypervisor machine my landscape server has been shut off in favor of a much more needed gitlab instance.

---

You did mention if you could use `ssmtp` instead.  Unfortunately, to my knowledge, the packages that install Landscape have a dependency on the `postfix` package - removing `ssmtp` will likely remove `postfix`, and that will probably remove Landscape.