# landscape registration

Tags: 14.04, server, landscape, patch

I am trying to use landscape for small environment consists of 5 vm ubuntu servers. I tried following 
[How do I install Landscape for personal use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549809/how-do-i-install-landscape-for-personal-use/724476#724476)
It lets me register on browser ->https://x.x.x.x/new-standalone-user and asks for Name, email, Passphrase then it says server not found.

Any thoughts? Any advice?

Comment: is the DNS name for your server valid?

Answer (score 0):

I think you installed using quickstart. If that's the case, it will redirect you to the $(hostname -f) of the server after that form. If that does not exist in DNS, the simplest solution for you now is to add that hostname to /etc/hosts with the correct IP on the machine where you are accessing landscape from.

Comment: could you give a few more details about this? Do you mean the host file should read something along the lines of "127.0.0.1 localhost" (first line) "<actual server IP> <server hostname> <server FQDN>"?