# Landscape - new-standalone-user fails?

Tags: landscape

Setup Landscape following the Manual install guide @ https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/ManualInstallation17.03

When I get to the end "Setup first user" the form loads and I fill it out. When I submit, the "Sign up" button just fades out, this was under Firefox 57. Under Google Chrome I get a redirect to "about:blank."

I have SSL setup properly with a Green Lock across all browsers. Setup appeared to go smoothly after I opened the port on the database server in the firewall. Both Database and Application server are Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS running in a production VMWare environment. Enterprise DNS is working along with SSL cert from Entrust so I do not think this is related @ [landscape registration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724483/landscape-registration)

Answer (score 0):

Check virtual host for both 80 and 443 in

> /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/(YOUR.LDS.FQDN).conf

Also you might try to restart landscape by

`lsctl restart`

Did you found anything interesting in

> /var/log/landscape-server/

directory and log files? Happy to review to see if anything can be found.

Also, did you know that there is an easy way to deploy Landscape with https://help.landscape.canonical.com/

```
sudo add-apt-repository -u ppa:landscape/17.03
sudo apt-get install landscape-server-quickstart
```