# Error Deploying Landscape with autopilot

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I'm trying to install Landscape OpenStack Autopilot following this tutorial http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-openstack-with-autopilot.

My distribution is Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS server, I have updated/upgraded the packages before the installation of MAAS.

I have 5 nodes in my setup, I have a gigabit connection, and I believe MAAS is correctly configured. I can deploy a node outside the installer (Landscape Autopilot), the node can reach the Internet, `ping google.com`, and `nslookup` works.

I thought this was a timeout issue, so I increases the timeout of /usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/controllers/install/multi.py file to 600 but this didn't resolve my issue.

I installed the package "juju" before launching installation.  I'm getting stuck during installation:

```
    [INFO: 02-17 09:13:07, openstack-install:227] Starting OpenStack Installer v0.99.27
[INFO: 02-17 09:13:07, openstack-install:228] Start command: ['/usr/bin/openstack-install']
[INFO: 02-17 09:13:07, openstack-install:239] Creating juju directories: /home/dylan/.cloud-install/juju
[INFO: 02-17 09:13:08, openstack-install:295] Running Liberty release
[INFO: 02-17 09:13:17, installbase.py:132] Performing a OpenStack Autopilot install
[INFO: 02-17 09:13:17, utils.py:771] pollinate: sudo su - -c 'pollinate -q -r --curl-opts "-k --user-agent uoi/182e63ab-487b-4662-a101-cd320ac40a23/IL"'
[DEBUG: 02-17 09:14:10, landscape.py:74] Existing MAAS defined, doing a LDS installation with existing MAAS.
[DEBUG: 02-17 09:14:55, multi.py:127] Bootstrapping Juju: JUJU_HOME=/home/dylan/.cloud-install/juju juju  bootstrap
[DEBUG: 02-17 09:27:30, multi.py:165] Finished MAAS step, now deploying Landscape.
[DEBUG: 02-17 09:43:13, multi.py:391] Running landscape configure: /usr/share/openstack/bin/configure-landscape --admin-email dlndaubie04@gmail.com --admin-name dylan --system-email dlndaubie04@gmail.com --maas-host 10.10.24.101
[INFO: 02-17 09:43:15, utils.py:771] pollinate: sudo su - -c 'pollinate -q -r --curl-opts "-k --user-agent uoi/182e63ab-487b-4662-a101-cd320ac40a23/ET"'
[ERROR: 02-17 09:43:16, multi.py:397] Problem with configuring Landscape: {'output': '', 'err': 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/share/openstack/bin/configure-landscape", line 209, in <module>\n    main()\n  File "/usr/share/openstack/bin/configure-landscape", line 202, in main\n    system_email=args.system_email)\n  File "/usr/share/openstack/bin/configure-landscape", line 173, in register_new_user\n    \'https://%s/api/\' % host)\n  File "/usr/share/openstack/bin/configure-landscape", line 126, in run_query\n    assert r.status_code == 200\nAssertionError\n', 'status': 1}.
[ERROR: 02-17 09:43:16, gui.py:267] A fatal error has occurred: Error configuring Landscape.

[DEBUG: 02-17 09:43:16, error.py:35] showing error view for: Error configuring Landscape.
[ERROR: 02-17 09:43:24, ev.py:130] Exception in ev.run():
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/ev.py", line 128, in run
    self.loop.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 278, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 376, in _run
    self.event_loop.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 1326, in run
    self._loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 276, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1172, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/events.py", line 120, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 393, in <lambda>
    event_loop, callback, self.get_available_raw_input())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 493, in parse_input
    callback(processed, processed_codes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 403, in _update
    self.process_input(keys)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 503, in process_input
    k = self._topmost_widget.keypress(self.screen_size, k)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/gui.py", line 136, in keypress
    return super().keypress(size, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 1128, in keypress
    return self.body.keypress( (maxcol, remaining), key )
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/decoration.py", line 836, in keypress
    return self._original_widget.keypress((maxcol,), key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 1587, in keypress
    key = self.focus.keypress(tsize, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/decoration.py", line 621, in keypress
    return self._original_widget.keypress(maxvals, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 1587, in keypress
    key = self.focus.keypress(tsize, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/wimp.py", line 535, in keypress
    self._emit('click')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/widget.py", line 463, in _emit
    signals.emit_signal(self, name, self, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/signals.py", line 264, in emit
    result |= self._call_callback(callback, user_arg, user_args, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/signals.py", line 294, in _call_callback
    return bool(callback(*args_to_pass))
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/ui/views/error.py", line 66, in cancel
    raise SystemExit("Install exited because of error.")
SystemExit: Install exited because of error.
[DEBUG: 02-17 09:43:24, utils.py:59] Juju Version: 1.25.3-trusty-amd64
[INFO: 02-17 09:43:24, utils.py:61] Cleanup, saving latest config object.
```

Could someone help me to resolve my issue? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help much with that openstack-install command, but something you could try, since you have MAAS already, is install Landscape on your own using juju:

https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/JujuDeployment15.11

After you have configured juju to use MAAS:

https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/config-maas

Use the `landscape-maas-dense` bundle. That will take one node from your MAAS to install all the landscape services.

Run `juju status` periodically to watch the deployment progress, and also keep an eye on the output of `juju debug-log`.

Once things are quiet there, hit the haproxy IP (you can get that from the `juju status` output) and follow the instructions to register.

Finally, once in the Landscape UI, go to the openstack tab and configure your cloud.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am able to deploy landscape now, but i had a problem with ssl keys, so i followed this tuto to resolve my problem : http://askubuntu.com/questions/549809/how-do-i-install-landscape-for-personal-use (I avoided ssl requirements by typing this command : juju-quickstart --no-browser u/landscape/landscape-dense-maas) Thanks for your help !!