# Error Deploying Landscape (Openstack Autopilot Installation)

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, cloud, openstack-autopilot

Trying to install openstack using autopilot.
juju bootstrap is successful but timeout while deploying landscape and installation fails.
Bootstrapping Juju finished, Preparing Landscape finished but it fails while Deploying Landscape.
Machine status is Deployed as shown in MAAS.
IP Forwarding is enabled.

commands.log file contents :

[

```
INFO: 08-01 15:58:08, openstack-install:227] Starting OpenStack Installer v0.99.28
[INFO: 08-01 15:58:08, openstack-install:228] Start command: ['/usr/bin/openstack-install']
[INFO: 08-01 15:58:08, openstack-install:239] Creating juju directories: /home/student/.cloud-install/juju
[INFO: 08-01 15:58:09, openstack-install:295] Running Liberty release
[INFO: 08-01 15:58:17, installbase.py:132] Performing an Autopilot install
[INFO: 08-01 15:58:17, utils.py:780] pollinate: sudo su - -c 'pollinate -q -r --curl-opts "-k --user-agent uoi/0f785e50-75d4-407f-a516-5247cfbdc02b/IL"'
[WARNING: 08-01 15:58:20, utils.py:783] Generating random seed failed: Command 'sudo su - -c 'pollinate -q -r --curl-opts "-k --user-agent uoi/0f785e50-75d4-407f-a516-5247cfbdc02b/IL"'' returned non-zero exit status 1
[DEBUG: 08-01 15:59:20, landscape.py:75] Existing MAAS defined, doing a LDS installation with existing MAAS.
[DEBUG: 08-01 15:59:30, utils.py:627] ssh keys exist for this user, they will be used instead.
[DEBUG: 08-01 15:59:30, multi.py:139] Bootstrapping Juju: JUJU_HOME=/home/student/.cloud-install/juju juju bootstrap
[DEBUG: 08-01 16:23:49, multi.py:177] Finished MAAS step, now deploying Landscape.
[INFO: 08-01 17:09:09, utils.py:780] pollinate: sudo su - -c 'pollinate -q -r --curl-opts "-k --user-agent uoi/0f785e50-75d4-407f-a516-5247cfbdc02b/ET"'
[ERROR: 08-01 17:09:11, multi.py:384] Problem deploying Landscape: {'output': '', 'err': "2016-08-01 16:24:06 [DEBUG] deployer.cli: Using runtime GoEnvironment on maas\n2016-08-01 16:24:06 [INFO] deployer.cli: Starting deployment of landscape-dense-maas\n2016-08-01 16:24:06 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Getting charms...\n2016-08-01 16:24:06 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /home/student/.cloud-install/juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_haproxy-16\n2016-08-01 16:24:06 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Retrieving store charm cs:trusty/haproxy-16\n2016-08-01 16:24:10 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /home/student/.cloud-install/juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_landscape-server\n2016-08-01 16:24:13 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Retrieving store charm cs:trusty/landscape-server-15\n2016-08-01 16:24:17 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /home/student/.cloud-install/juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_postgresql-40\n2016-08-01 16:24:17 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Retrieving store charm cs:trusty/postgresql-40\n2016-08-01 16:24:21 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /home/student/.cloud-install/juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_rabbitmq-server-43\n2016-08-01 16:24:21 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Retrieving store charm cs:trusty/rabbitmq-server-43\n2016-08-01 16:24:25 [DEBUG] deployer.deploy: Resolving configuration\n2016-08-01 16:24:25 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Connecting to environment...\n2016-08-01 16:24:26 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Connected to environment\n2016-08-01 16:24:26 [INFO] deployer.import: Deploying services...\n2016-08-01 16:24:26 [INFO] deployer.import: Deploying service haproxy using cs:trusty/haproxy-16\n2016-08-01 16:24:26 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Refetching status for placement deploys\n2016-08-01 16:24:47 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Setting annotations\n2016-08-01 16:24:48 [INFO] deployer.import: Deploying service landscape-server using cs:trusty/landscape-server\n2016-08-01 16:25:11 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Setting annotations\n2016-08-01 16:25:11 [INFO] deployer.import: Deploying service postgresql using cs:trusty/postgresql-40\n2016-08-01 16:25:28 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Setting annotations\n2016-08-01 16:25:28 [INFO] deployer.import: Deploying service rabbitmq-server using cs:trusty/rabbitmq-server-43\n2016-08-01 16:25:41 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Setting annotations\n2016-08-01 16:25:47 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Adding units...\n2016-08-01 16:25:47 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Service 'haproxy' does not need any more units added.\n2016-08-01 16:25:47 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Service 'landscape-server' does not need any more units added.\n2016-08-01 16:25:47 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Service 'postgresql' does not need any more units added.\n2016-08-01 16:25:47 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Service 'rabbitmq-server' does not need any more units added.\n2016-08-01 16:25:47 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Waiting for units before adding relations\n2016-08-01 17:06:10 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta machine: 0/lxc/0 change:pending\n2016-08-01 17:06:20 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta machine: 0/lxc/1 change:pending\n2016-08-01 17:06:30 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta machine: 0/lxc/2 change:pending\n2016-08-01 17:06:40 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta machine: 0/lxc/3 change:pending\n2016-08-01 17:06:40 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: haproxy/0 change:pending\n2016-08-01 17:06:40 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta machine: 0/lxc/1 change:pending\n2016-08-01 17:06:40 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta machine: 0/lxc/0 change:started\n2016-08-01 17:06:45 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta machine: 0/lxc/1 change:started\n2016-08-01 17:06:45 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: haproxy/0 change:pending\n2016-08-01 17:06:45 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: landscape-server/0 change:pending\n2016-08-01 17:06:50 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: landscape-server/0 change:pending\n2016-08-01 17:06:50 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta service: haproxy change:{u'Err': None, u'Since': u'2016-08-01T11:36:44.497599412Z', u'Current': u'maintenance', u'Version': u'', u'Message': u'installing charm software', u'Data': {}}\n2016-08-01 17:06:50 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: haproxy/0 change:pending\n2016-08-01 17:06:50 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta service: landscape-server change:{u'Err': None, u'Since': u'2016-08-01T11:36:45.12038557Z', u'Current': u'maintenance', u'Version': u'', u'Message': u'installing charm software', u'Data': {}}\n2016-08-01 17:06:50 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: landscape-server/0 change:pending\n2016-08-01 17:06:50 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta machine: 0/lxc/2 change:started\n2016-08-01 17:06:50 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: postgresql/0 change:pending\n2016-08-01 17:06:55 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: postgresql/0 change:pending\n2016-08-01 17:06:56 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta service: postgresql change:{u'Err': None, u'Since': u'2016-08-01T11:36:50.489477312Z', u'Current': u'maintenance', u'Version': u'', u'Message': u'installing charm software', u'Data': {}}\n2016-08-01 17:06:56 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: postgresql/0 change:pending\n2016-08-01 17:07:01 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta machine: 0/lxc/3 change:pending\n2016-08-01 17:07:01 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: rabbitmq-server/0 change:pending\n2016-08-01 17:07:01 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta machine: 0/lxc/3 change:started\n2016-08-01 17:07:06 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: rabbitmq-server/0 change:pending\n2016-08-01 17:07:06 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta service: rabbitmq-server change:{u'Err': None, u'Since': u'2016-08-01T11:37:02.046068604Z', u'Current': u'maintenance', u'Version': u'', u'Message': u'installing charm software', u'Data': {}}\n2016-08-01 17:07:06 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: rabbitmq-server/0 change:pending\n2016-08-01 17:07:11 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta service: postgresql change:{u'Err': None, u'Since': u'2016-08-01T11:37:06.907394189Z', u'Current': u'maintenance', u'Version': u'', u'Message': u'Running preinstallation hooks', u'Data': {}}\n2016-08-01 17:07:11 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: postgresql/0 change:started\n2016-08-01 17:07:16 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta service: postgresql change:{u'Err': None, u'Since': u'2016-08-01T11:37:09.672721533Z', u'Current': u'maintenance', u'Version': u'', u'Message': u'Configuring software sources', u'Data': {}}\n2016-08-01 17:07:16 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: postgresql/0 change:started\n2016-08-01 17:07:26 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: haproxy/0 change:pending\n2016-08-01 17:07:41 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta service: postgresql change:{u'Err': None, u'Since': u'2016-08-01T11:37:38.233417076Z', u'Current': u'maintenance', u'Version': u'', u'Message': u'Installing packages', u'Data': {}}\n2016-08-01 17:07:41 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: postgresql/0 change:started\n2016-08-01 17:07:56 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta service: haproxy change:{u'Err': None, u'Since': u'2016-08-01T11:37:51.298410772Z', u'Current': u'unknown', u'Version': u'', u'Message': u'', u'Data': {}}\n2016-08-01 17:07:56 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: haproxy/0 change:started\n2016-08-01 17:07:56 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: haproxy/0 change:started\n2016-08-01 17:08:01 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: haproxy/0 change:started\n2016-08-01 17:08:31 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta service: postgresql change:{u'Err': None, u'Since': u'2016-08-01T11:38:26.328189543Z', u'Current': u'maintenance', u'Version': u'', u'Message': u'Removing hold on charm packages', u'Data': {}}\n2016-08-01 17:08:31 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: postgresql/0 change:started\n2016-08-01 17:08:41 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta service: postgresql change:{u'Err': None, u'Since': u'2016-08-01T11:38:38.307360637Z', u'Current': u'maintenance', u'Version': u'', u'Message': u'Starting PostgreSQL', u'Data': {}}\n2016-08-01 17:08:41 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: postgresql/0 change:started\n2016-08-01 17:08:46 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta service: postgresql change:{u'Err': None, u'Since': u'2016-08-01T11:38:41.900984811Z', u'Current': u'maintenance', u'Version': u'', u'Message': u'Started', u'Data': {}}\n2016-08-01 17:08:46 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: postgresql/0 change:started\n2016-08-01 17:08:56 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta service: postgresql change:{u'Err': None, u'Since': u'2016-08-01T11:38:49.43785689Z', u'Current': u'active', u'Version': u'', u'Message': u'Live master', u'Data': {}}\n2016-08-01 17:08:56 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: postgresql/0 change:started\n2016-08-01 17:08:56 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: postgresql/0 change:started\n2016-08-01 17:09:01 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta service: postgresql change:{u'Err': None, u'Since': u'2016-08-01T11:38:58.559409116Z', u'Current': u'active', u'Version': u'', u'Message': u'Live master', u'Data': {}}\n2016-08-01 17:09:01 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Delta unit: postgresql/0 change:started\n2016-08-01 17:09:05 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Connecting to environment...\n2016-08-01 17:09:09 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Connected to environment\n2016-08-01 17:09:09 [ERROR] deployer.import: Reached deployment timeout.. exiting\n2016-08-01 17:09:09 [INFO] deployer.cli: Deployment stopped. run time: 2702.89\n", 'status': 1}
[ERROR: 08-01 17:09:11, gui.py:269] A fatal error has occurred: Error deploying Landscape.

>[ERROR: 08-01 17:09:11, gui.py:270] Error deploying Landscape.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 54, in run
result = self.fn(self.args, *self.kwargs)
File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/controllers/install/multi.py", line 181, in do_install
self.loop).run()
File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/controllers/install/multi.py", line 319, in run
self.deploy_landscape()
File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/controllers/install/multi.py", line 344, in deploy_landscape
self.run_deployer()
File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/controllers/install/multi.py", line 385, in run_deployer
raise Exception("Error deploying Landscape.")
Exception: Error deploying Landscape.
[DEBUG: 08-01 17:09:11, error.py:35] showing error view for: Error deploying Landscape.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend simplifying the solution down until you find the source of the problem.  This answer gives great tips on how to do that:

https://askubuntu.com/a/739073/7056