# Landscape Server Problem

Tags: 14.04, landscape

I installed the Landscape server as described here:

[How do I install Landscape for personal use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549809/how-do-i-install-landscape-for-personal-use)

I did this on a local server a couple of weeks ago and it worked perfectly. But now when I try to log in, this screen comes up.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFuJC.jpg)

Any tips on how to solve this issue? The Ubuntu version is 14.04

Answer (score 0):

You need to login on the `landscape-server` unit (usually `landscape-server/0`) and inspect the running processes. In particular, you can use the `lsctl` tool like this: `sudo lsctl status`. `restart`, `stop` and `start` also work.

That error means that at least the appserver isn't running.

Comment: Here is the output of the lsctl looks like everthing is running `# lsctl status
== landscape-appserver ==
 * appserver 1 is running
== landscape-async-frontend ==
 * async-frontend 1 is running
== landscape-job-handler ==
 * job-handler 1 is running
== landscape-msgserver ==
 * message-server 1 is running
== landscape-pingserver ==
 * pingserver 1 is running
== landscape-api ==
 * api 1 is running
== landscape-juju-sync ==
 * juju-sync 1 is running
== landscape-package-upload ==
 * package-upload 1 is running
== landscape-package-search ==
landscape-package-search start/running, process 11646`

Comment: Inspect `juju status`, see if there are hook errors. Other than that, login on the haproxy unit and start tracing the connection's path from there to the backend, something broke... Look at haproxy.cfg for the ports and addresses. You can also probably hit the haproxy unit on port 10000 iirc (the haproxy.cfg file will have the details under "monitoring") to see the backend status.

Comment: When i `juju status` this comes ERROR Unable to connect to environment "".
Please check your credentials or use 'juju bootstrap' to create a new environment.

Error details:
no environment specified
`'