# How to set up Landscape On-Premises on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: server, 16.04, landscape

As I know that some things are changing with every new release of Canonical Landscape ... I want to find out how to install and use Landscape On-Premises (formerly Landscape Dedicated Server) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS edition - for which the new current version 16.06 of Landscape is available. I read -> [How do I install Landscape for personal use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549809/how-do-i-install-landscape-for-personal-use) But for Ubuntu 16.04 - there are differences.