# Deploy of Landscape Client on a node

Tags: landscape

Lab:

All virtual environment has been realised using Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and so composed:

- 1 VM for MAAS (memory: 8GB, CPU: 1, HDD: 500GB);
- 1 VM for JUJU GUI (memory: 8GB, CPU: 1, HDD: 500GB);
- 1 VM for LANDSCAPE dense MAAS (memory: 8GB, CPU: 1, HDD: 500GB);
- 1 VM for Apache2 and LANDSCAPE client;

until the deploy of juju, Landscape server and Apache2 were all well, now I'd like to deploy Landscape Client on that node. 
As I done for Apache service I've deployed landscape-client via cli on the same node of Apache, but the result has been that:

[image]
[image]

while juju status presents this screen

[image]

someone can help me or suggest the procedure to make that actives on the node?

Answer (score 1):

The landscape-client charm is a **subordinate application**.  I can't find docs in the latest Juju (2.x), but it's the same concept as the [Juju 1.25 Subordinate Service documentation](https://jujucharms.com/docs/1.25/authors-subordinate-services).  Charms like these do not get units assigned to them, but rather relate to other applications in your model.

In your case, you need to **relate** `landscape-client` to `apache2`, then when you add new `apache2` units, landscape-client will be installed and configured in the same way each time.

See the [landscape-client juju charm entry](https://jujucharms.com/landscape-client/) for more information on how to use it.