# Problem installing Landscape on 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, landscape

I've googled around but have not found a solution to my Landscape installations problem.

When I run: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:landscape/17.03`
I get:

```
muff@landscape:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:landscape/17.03
[sudo] password for muff:

 More info: https://launchpad.net/~landscape/+archive/ubuntu/17.03
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/16.06/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/17.03/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/16.06/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/17.03/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/16.06/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/17.03/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
muff@landscape:~$
```

When I run: `sudo apt-get update`
I get:

```
muff@landscape:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/16.06/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/17.03/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/16.06/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/17.03/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/16.06/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/17.03/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
muff@landscape:~$
```

And when I run: `sudo apt-get install landscape-server-quickstart`
I get:

```
muff@landscape:~$ sudo apt-get install landscape-server-quickstart
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package landscape-server-quickstart
muff@landscape:~$
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

P.S
For example I've been reading:

- [How do I install Landscape for personal use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549809/how-do-i-install-landscape-for-personal-use/808912)
- https://launchpad.net/~landscape/+archive/ubuntu/17.03
- https://help.landscape.canonical.com/FrontPage?highlight=%28%28LDS%7CQuickstartDeployment17.03%29%29
- [Force update from unsigned repository Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732985/force-update-from-unsigned-repository-ubuntu-16-04)
- [Landscape PPA not working 16.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/985917/landscape-ppa-not-working-16-04lts)
- https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/QuickstartDeployment17.03
- https://landscape.canonical.com/set-up-on-prem
- https://help.landscape.canonical.com/?action=show&redirect=LDS

Comment: "ppa. .../landscape" : The latest included OS is Ubuntu 16.02 → http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/16.06/ubuntu/dists/

Comment: Landscape *Server* is not available for 18.04 yet, while the landscape client that interfaces with the server is.  Their latest Ubuntu release they support for the server is 16.04.  There is no documentation on when 18.04 will be supported for the Landscape Server components.

Comment: @MrPew I've added a better 'answer' now.

Comment: Please also do not edit your title to say "Solved", rather accept an answer or provide an answer yourself.  (Note that I've converted my comment to an answer now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NOTICE: This post was written back in late April of 2018.  The information in this answer may no longer be up to date; you will have to refer to the [Landscape Dedicated Server](https://help.landscape.canonical.com/?action=show&redirect=LDS) documentation page on the Landscape/Canonical Help Documentation to determine if your target version of Ubuntu is supported for Landscape Dedicated Server.
>
> At the time this answer was written, 18.04 was not yet supported for LDS.  Even though this has changed, this answer is being left alone for historical purposes. (for now)

Landscape *Server* software is not available for 18.04 yet; however, the landscape *client* which interacts with Landscape Server *is* available in 18.04.

The Landscape Server components are last 'guaranteed' to work with 16.04, and in fact that is the latest OS supported by Landscape Server.

From https://help.landscape.canonical.com/?action=show&redirect=LDS (accessed on April 30, 2018), we get this pretty "support" table detailing the supported OSes:

[image]

And as you can see, they only support 16.04 currently.  (Landscape doesn't immediately adapt to the 'latest and greatest' shortly after release, they never have and don't even do this up at the Canonical Landscape Cloud instances.)

Currently, there is no public documentation detailing a support timeline for Landscape.  There probably will be support at some point, but it's not information that's been made public.

Comment: Damn I just spun up an 18.04 VM to run it.   Any workaround or do I have to dial back to 16.04?

Comment: @AlanObject This answer was written back in April, it may or may not be obsolete anymore.  You will have to refer to the linked Landscape documentation to determine if you can install Landscape into 18.04.  It looks like it may now be possible, but it's untested by me.  (However, I am not rewriting the answer completely, I've added a notice that the info in the answer may be out of date and you would have to refer to the documentation for compatibility determination)

Answer (score 1):

As of a while back there is LDS support for 18.04 (see https://help.landscape.canonical.com/?action=show&redirect=LDS).

In essence for running on premise:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -u ppa:landscape/18.03
sudo apt-get install landscape-server-quickstart
```

Check out the link above for other configuration options.