# Python Landscape

Tags: python3

I found a Python package named landscape. It will be installed by initial setup in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape

I would like to know what is that for and how to make it run with other versions of python. For example with Python Virtual Environment (pyenv).

---

I did not know that Landscape management tool. I will have a look. Thanks.
The reason I opened this issue, is, I could not find a python package to install the landscape API.

If you install pyenv to run multiple python versions the update-modt script fails to run. I tracked that down to

```
/usr/share/landscape/landscape-sysinfo.wrapper
/usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo
```

and found that landscape-sysinfo wont run in /usr/bin. If you copy this file e.g. to /usr/share/landscape/ and change the path in landscape-sysinfo.wrapper, it runs.

This is very weird.

Answer (score 2):

A [search here in AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064505/cant-register-landscape-client-with-on-prem-server) using the search term "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape" shows a Python package named Landscape is part of Canonical's [Landscape](https://landscape.canonical.com/) management tool to deploy, monitor and manage multiple Ubuntu servers.

If you have multiple Ubuntu servers to manage, you can read more about it at https://landscape.canonical.com/static/doc/api/python-api.html .